# Community User Profile Views

Tags: discussion, profile-page, community-user

What is going on with [Community's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) profile views? I highly doubt that he/she/it has only 649 profile views. He/She/It has been a member of our community for 7 years and 8 months appearing constantly in reviews, tag creations and a protagonist to various popular question like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user). I tend to believe that the counter is disabled and doesn't get updated. But why at 649? Is there a symbolism behind the number? And why disable the counter in the first place? Machine discrimination much?

The Meta Exchange page [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) has 1,724 profile views, which also seems implausible, but it seems to get updated properly.

Comment: Maybe the integer overflowed?

Comment: I don't think it's possible that it reached 2147483647 profile views :P. Why voting for closure? If you don't think curiosity is an adequate reason to keep the question, consider it a bug report.

Comment: The close reason being cast is "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail. See also: What is "meta"? How does it work?". I don't know why though.

Comment: Yes, it's discrimination against machines. See [Community user profile page view count and last seen date woes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118672)